# Is it possible to display data from SeatGeek API call on my Squarespace site?

Tags: code-injection, squarespace

Is it possible to connect to the [SeatGeek API](https://platform.seatgeek.com/) to display local event data on a Squarespace site?

The [Squarespace API docs](https://developers.squarespace.com/commerce-apis/what-can-i-do) all seem directed towards commerce-related goals.

I am familiar with how to connect to the SeatGeek API in the context of a mobile application.  But I don't know whether connecting to APIs (other than those listed for commerce) from within a Squarespace is doable.

SeatGeek would be an [unofficial integration](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000975547) .  I've posted on the squarespace forums with no response, so asking here to see if anyone out there knows about it.

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Squarespace websites above the ["Personal" plan tier](https://www.squarespace.com/pricing) support the addition of custom JavaScript via [Code Blocks](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206543167-Code-Blocks) and [Code Injection](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815908-Using-Code-Injection).

Therefore, if SeatGeek supports using their API via JavaScript (and it appears that they do), then you can obtain the data from within your Squarespace website.

Where within your site the code is added and what initialization methods are used will vary on a case-by-case basis. For example, factors include: whether you are using Squarespace 7.0 or 7.1 and whether the template you're using supports [AJAX Loading](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000253288-Ajax-loading) and has it enabled.

However, regardless of where the code is added and the initialization methods used, it looks to me, based on [what I see here](https://rapidapi.com/seatgeek/api/seatgeek), that obtaining data from SeatGeek via JavaScript is possible. (Select "*JavaScript > XMLHttpRequest*" or "*JavaScript > Fetch*" from the upper-right "*Code Snippet*" panel where it says "*(Node.js) Unirest*" by default):

```
var data = null;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
});

xhr.open("GET", "https://seatgeek-seatgeekcom.p.rapidapi.com/events");
xhr.setRequestHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "seatgeek-seatgeekcom.p.rapidapi.com");
xhr.setRequestHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "SIGN-UP-FOR-KEY");

xhr.send(data);
```

Or, via fetch:

```
fetch("https://seatgeek-seatgeekcom.p.rapidapi.com/events", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "seatgeek-seatgeekcom.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "SIGN-UP-FOR-KEY"
    }
})
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

While it varies on a case-by-case basis, in most cases you'll want to use the sitewide code injection area vs. code blocks or page-level code injection. Then, on Squarespace 7.0 sites, you'll want to wrap your code in:

```
window.Squarespace.onInitialize(Y, function() {
  // do stuff here
});
```

For Squarespace 7.1 sites on the other hand, one would usually wrap the code in:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // do stuff here
}, false);
```

Finally, you'll need to think about how you're outputting the data. You could either add HTML markup via a Code Block in the body of the target page, or add the markup to the page as part of your JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, Brandon.  A few notes:  I’m using squarepace 7.0 for Adirondack Template from Adirondack family, which according to [this](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000253288-Ajax-loading) does not support Ajax.

Comment: I am more familiar with Fetch than I am with XMLHttpRequest, so I tried with Fetch and got some data!  Here is my code: `<script>
  let response = fetch(
    "https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?per_page=100&venue.city=boston&client_id=MYAPIKEY
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => console.log(response.events[0].title));
</script>
`

Comment: Glad to see it's working. That's correct that Adirondack does not use Ajax loading. So, that excludes it as a concern, as mentioned in my answer. Fetch is also an alternative. I'm curious, what is the reason for unaccepting the answer?

Comment: Hey Brandon - when I exhumed this after two months my thinking (basically due to noobness) was that I should wait until we reached the end of the conversation/process/comments to check any answer, so I unaccepted.  But your answer is correct - it definitely is possible to achieve what I want here - and secondary questions of mine branching from there are questions that I should repackage as new, more focused questions.  Your answer is valid.  Accepted again.  I'll ask a new question about **how** to achieve what I want now that I know it's possible thanks to your help!